# Change Font Colors and Style for TeXlipse Only in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, texlipse

Having just installed the TeXlipse plugin onto Eclipse 4.5, I am having a difficulty figuring out whether there is a way to change how Eclipse highlights the TeX code. At the moment, I am using the dark theme for Eclipse and the colors (dark blue, purple, etc) it chooses for TeX are hard to see. I would like, however, to leave all the styling for Java code as is.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window > Preferences > Texlipse > Editor > Syntax Highlighting, there you can change colors and font type.

Comment: Thank you! And than I had to restart Eclipse to realize changes.